# Unable to remove and add items in multiselect dropdown list

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-multiselect

I am having problem to remove and add new items in multiselect dropdown list. The mutliselect dropdown list not changing at all. What I'm trying to do is to empty all items in the multiselect dropdown list with id #to before appending new items into the same list. However, the old items are still existing in my dropdown list.

```
$('#toList').change(function() {
    $("#to").empty();
    var toList = $("#toList").val();
    $.post("${createLink(controller:'account', action: 'setList')}", {
       toList: toList
    },
    function(result) {
        if (result.status) {
           $.each(result["toList"], function (i, item) {
               if (item != null && item != "") {
                   $('#to').append($('<option>', {
                       value: item,
                       text : item
                   }));
               }
           });
       }
   });
   $("#to").multiselect('reload');
})
```

Comment: You are calling `multiselect('reload')` outside the success handler of the post request.  That's an issue.

Comment: I'm able to do it by using multiselect( 'rebuild' ). Thanks !